# My return value function is failing - Promise related I think

Tags: javascript, json, knockout.js, ecma

**The Problem**
I am working on a simple login page. From within my view model script, I call another script which handles the calls to my API.

In short, I am not getting back the expected data I want, which is simply a token string ( which indicates the login was successful ).

**Here is the mock Json I am using**

```
[
    {
      "id":1,
      "firstName":"John",
      "lastName":"Smith",
      "email":"john@gmail.com",
      "token" : "65456j4h56j4h6gjk4g6k7g6k5g7jh567"
    }
  ]
```

**My View Model Script**

```
import {user} from "../shared/user-service.js";
import {token} from "../shared/token-service.js";


// Login View Model
var LoginViewModel = function () {

    self = this;

    this.token = ko.observable();
    this.email = ko.observable("john@gmail.com");
    this.password = ko.observable("12345");

    self.submit = function () {
        var oUser = {
            email: self.email(),
            password: self.password()
        };

        // I am not getting back desired results here
        var loginResponse = user.login(oUser);
        alert(loginResponse.token);


    }

}; // End View Model


ko.applyBindings(new LoginViewModel());
```

**and, finally, here is my user-service file:**

```
let user = {

    getUserSession: function () {
        var user = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('user'));
        console.log(`Getting User from Session: value = ${user} `);
        return user;
    },

    setUserSession: function (objUser) {
        var user = JSON.stringify(objUser);
        sessionStorage.setItem("user", user);
        console.log(`Setting User in Session: value = ${user} `);
    },



    login: function (objUser) {

        return fetch('../api/user/login.json', {
                method: "GET",
                headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
            })
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((responseData) => {
                console.log(responseData);
                return responseData;
            })
            .catch(error => console.warn(error));
    }




};

/* Helper Functions */
function handleErrors(response) {
    if (!response.ok) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
        throw Error(response.statusText);
    }
    return response;
}

export {
    user
};
```

**Screenshot Of Console.Log Data**
[image: Login Screenshot]

and here is the value of the alert from within my login-view-model.js...

**Undefined Result**
[image: Undefined]

Essentially, ***I just want to login the user***. If valid, grab the token the API is returning, and save it to session. If a token was not returned, simply alert.

I don't know why this is proving so difficult for me. I really would appreciate some guidance on this one.

Oh, of course, you see I am just testing with this mock-data. Once I get this functioning, I will convert it to a POST and a real URL.

Thank you for reading this.

John

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Problem 1

Your JSON data is not read properly.

#### Quick Solution

Your response is an **array** of objects. You first need to find the right object in it before accessing its properties. If its always the same (the first one), simple access to `[0]` will work:

```
// I am not getting back desired results here
var loginResponse = user.login(oUser);
alert(loginResponse[0].token); // <-- Add [0]
```

Otherwise, you will have to iterate over it with a loop.

#### Better Solution

If you know that you always only get **one** or **zero** objects (depending on if it was successful or not), you could simply **return the object** in the server code and **not an array of one object**.

### Problem 2

You don't handle your Promise properly. You can't return out of a then block. You should either return a Promise or make the function async. Check the snippet:

```
login: function (objUser) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { // <-- return a promise and not the fetch method
        fetch('../api/user/login.json', {
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
        })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseData) => {
            console.log(responseData);
            resolve(responseData); // <-- "return" the data
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.warn(error);
            reject(error); // <-- reject if failed
        });
    })
}
```

And you need to change the other part accordingly:

```
// I am not getting back desired results here
user.login(oUser).then(response => {
   alert(response[0].token);
});
```

Comment: I added the 0 , now getting this:  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'token' of undefined

Comment: @JohnS. Check the answer. Updated

Comment: @ MauriceNino  - what a well thought out response to my problem. It works fine now - and more importantly, I learned WHY it wasn't working.  I was getting caught up in trying to return data from within a THEN - which I never knew you couldn't do. Thanks a million!

Comment: @JohnS. No problem! Glad I could help. Also, one more hint: If you don't like `.then()` chains, you can read into async/await pattern. Its way cleaner than the promise returning.

Comment: Wow, again @MauriceNino - another fantastic suggestion. Yes, I have decided to take that approach, as it is easier for me.